# What is wrong with JPQL (count and select)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, subquery

Below is the query to get rows from parent table and count of each id from child table.

```
@Query("SELECT cnt idcount, person FROM Person person,(SELECT COUNT(child.id) cnt FROM Child child WHERE child.id :input_id) idcount WHERE person.id :input_id")
List<Person> searchPersonWithCount(@Param("input_id") Long input_id);
```

I get below error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: idcount near line 1, column 12 [SELECT cnt idcount, person FROM com.myc.cc.domain.Person person,(SELECT COUNT(child.id) cnt FROM com.myc.cc.domain.Child child WHERE child.id :input_id) idcount WHERE person.id :input_id]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
```

When I execute this is in oracle sqldeveloper i am able to get results.

Native query executed in Qracle sql developer:

```
select  cnt idcount, person.* from Person person,(select count(*) cnt from Child child WHERE id = '1235') idcount WHERE id = '1235'
```

Result:

```
IDCOUNT         ID          NAME
   2          1235         PersonA
```

can anyone please let me know what is wrong in the JPQL.

Thanks in advance.

SAMPLE DATA :

PARENT Table:

```
ID         NAME

1001      sampleNameA
1002      sampleNameB
1003      sampleNameC
```

CHILD Table:

```
ID        NAME       INTERESTS

1001     sampleNameA    music   
1001     sampleNameA    dance
1001     sampleNameA    coding
1003     sampleNameC    music   
1002     sampleNameB    dance
1002     sampleNameB    coding
```

If id = 1001,

Expected output is

```
COUNT   ID         NAME

3   1001      sampleNameA
```

Comment: It appears that it doesn't like `idcount` in `SELECT cnt idcount`. Try changing this to `cnt as idcount`. Best of luck.

Comment: Is `idcount` the second table alias? try `SELECT idcount.cnt`.

Comment: Thanks. Both solution cleared the error but now i get some other error

Comment: I am not convinced with the query to find the count for each parent id in child table. The inline view seems not necessary. What is the key to join the parent and child table? Could you please post some sample data and desired output.

Comment: @LalitKumarB The key to join tables is id. I have posted sample data and expected output

Comment: Just to be sure. Exactly why aren't you using SQL for this?